# c# System.MissingMethodException in sqlite3

Tags: c#, exception, sqlite, missingmethodexception

I'm making a c# application which uses sqlite3 database. For sqlite, I'm using [System.Data.SQLite.dll](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki). The problem is on some systems the program works fine, but on others, it throws `System.MissingMethodException` while reading the database.

This is the code I'm using for reading :

```
using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection con = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("data source=" + file_name))
{
    using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand com = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand(con))
    {
        con.Open();
        com.CommandText = "Select * FROM my_table;";

        using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader["field1"] + " : " + reader["field2"] +" : " + reader["field3"]);

                if(reader["field1"].ToString().Equals("1"))
                {
                    xlWorkSheetR1.Cells[i, 2] = reader["field1"];
                    xlWorkSheetR1.Cells[i, 3] = reader["field2"];
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

And this is the error I'm getting :

[image]

Can you please tell me what is causing this exception ? And how to avoid it ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if

1. Version of System.Data.SQLite.dll is same across all machines
2. Version of .NET frameworks installed on these machines

Comment: System.Data.SQLite.dll is deployed along with the application so that shouldn't be a problem. The minimum .NET version the app supports is higher than the version installed on the system on which this exception occurred. But I have made a ClickOnce installer and a standalone executeble ( containing the required dependencies ). Will I still have to update the .NET version on the system ??

Comment: Can you list the version of the .NET framework you are targeting along with the framework version on the deployed machine and the machine on which the exe was built. You are most likely facing the issue listed here https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1097462/missingmethodexception-additional-information-method-not-found-0-system-array-empty

Comment: The app is targeting v4.5 and te one currently installed is v3.5